# Starting with Visual Studio Code for Java with Maven

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm coming back to my origin of Java development. I'm use to work in C# with Nuget packages. I have basic notion of Maven. I would like to use VSC (Visual Studio Code).

I'm looking how I can import my first package to use a function/method `ByteUtils`. It seems this method come from an Apache package.

So here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>testGroupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <name>artifactId</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
      <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
      <version>21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

And a screenshot with the issue:

[image]

[image]

[image]

> The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\xxxx.m2\repository\org\apache\apache\21\apache-21.jar'
>   Missing artifact org.apache:apache:jar:21

To be complete here is my app.java

```
package testGroupId;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        MessageDigest md = null;
        try
        {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        //byte[] theDigest = md.digest(ByteUtils.intToBytesBigEndian(123456789))
        System.out.println("Hello Java");
    }
}
```

My question. Why ny org.apache dependency cannot be loaded or downloaded?

Comment: Are you able to build from command prompt?

Comment: Before adding my dependency org.apache yes

Comment: Maybe my dependency is wrongly referenced? It is a problem of reference. When I remove it from pom.xml I can build again. I can build with VSC and with the "compile" option of Maven Project section.

Comment: FYI: [*Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code*](https://inside.java/2023/10/18/announcing-vscode-extension/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The artifact [`org.apache:apache:pom:21`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/21/apache-21.pom) is not a JAR artifact instead it is a POM artifact which can be used as a parent for you maven module or can be used in the depencyManagement section.

If you add a POM artifact as normal dependency maven will try to download the jar file for the artifact but it doesn't exist thus the error.

To add as a parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
    <version>21</version>
</parent>
```

To add it in the dependencyManagement

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
      <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
      <version>21</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

If you want to [`org.apache.commons.compress.utils.ByteUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/utils/ByteUtils.html) then you have to add the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Are you sure. I cannot find where is this ByteUtils coming from.

Comment: @BastienVandamme your code do not have the class referred. Could you please tell the full class with the package.

Comment: @BastienVandamme if you want to use `org.apache.commons.compress.utils.ByteUtils` then you have to add `org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.18` as dependency.

Comment: Yes but in comment. ```org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.18``` How do you know that?

Comment: @BastienVandamme I used google and https://mvnrepository.com/ to search for the specific artifact contains the class.

Comment: The version 1.18 doesn't have any intToBytesBigEndian or byteToIntBigEndian method. Great... I think I remember why I left Java world. And the guy that gave me this piece of code probably never cross checked it.

Comment: This not a Java only problem if you want to use a library to achieve something you have to know that particular library.